# Rspec expect not working and getting success

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, rspec

I wrote the following code:

```
require_relative '../ticket'
describe Ticket do
  before do
    @ticket = Ticket.new()
  end
  context "exit" do
    it 'check_exit' do
      result = @ticket.ticket_viewer("quit")
      expect(result).to include("Thanks")
    end
  end
end

 class Ticket
 def ticket_viewer(user_response)
    # display information on command line as per user response
    if user_response == "menu"
        puts "\n\t\tSelect view options:"
        puts "\t\tPress 1 to view all Tickets"
        puts "\t\tPress 2 to view a Ticket"
        puts "\t\tType 'quit' to exit"
        view_option = gets.chomp.downcase
        if view_option == "1"
            puts "Downloading tickets from the API ..."
            # call show_tickets to display all the tickets
            show_tickets(1)
        elsif view_option == "2"
            do something ...
        elsif view_option == "quit"
            puts "Thanks for using Ticket Viewer"
        else
            puts "\nPlease key in valid option"
            puts "============================="
            ticket_viewer("menu")
        end
    elsif user_response == "quit"
        puts "Thanks for using Ticket Viewer"
        exit
    else
        puts "\nPlease key in valid option"
        puts "============================"
        ticket_viewer("menu")
    end
end
end
```

When I try to execute, expect(result).to eq("something")

does not work. The case is passed no matter what the value is in `eg("something")`.
If someone could help me how to write my rspec

Comment: Can you post `ticket.rb`?

Comment: In general you should post the minimum code sample that reproduces your problem. For example do not include that commented out code , or tests that are ok. Do include the misbehaving test and enough of the ticket mode to reproduce the problem.